# Traer datos mediante un select en Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

Estoy realizando un proyecto en donde por medio de un select yo escojo a un proveedor y me traiga los datos de la base de datos de dicho proveedor ejemplo (selecciono al proveedor electricos sas y me traer su telefono email direccion y tipo) he intentado hacerlo pero lo único que he podido hacer es que me traiga los proveedores al select y setee el nombre a un input. Me podrían decir como puedo hacer para traer esos datos y mostrarlos en los input ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

con este traigo el nombre de los proveedores y su id

```
    <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
   <label >Provider</label>

      <select id='select'  class="form-control">
        <option selected disabled readonly>Choose...</option>
        @foreach($categorias as $categoria)
        <option value="{{$categoria['id']}}">{{$categoria['name']}}</option>
       @endforeach
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

he leido que se debe de  hacer con un script pero no he logrado hacerlo

```
     $(document).ready(function()
  {
    $("#select").change(function()
    {
      $("#email").val("gfd");
    });

  });
```

porque no se como relacionar el id del proveedor con los campos
que son estos

```
 <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-5">
    

              <div class="form-group row">
                  
                   <div class="col-md-4">
                <input class="" type="text" id="type" name="type" readonly style="width: 250px" value="">
                 </div>  

             </div>
             <div class="form-group row">
                  
                   <div class="col-md-4">
                <input class="" type="text" id="address" name="address" readonly style="width: 250px" value="">
                 </div>  
                 
             </div>
             <div class="form-group row">
                  
                   <div class="col-md-4">
                <input class="" type="text"  id="email" name="email" readonly style="width: 250px" value="">
                 </div>  
                 
             </div>
             <div class="form-group row">
                  
                   <div class="col-md-4">
                <input class="" type="text" id="telephone" name="telephone" readonly style="width: 250px" value="">
                 </div>  
                 
             </div>
             <div class="form-group row">
                  
                   <div class="col-md-4">
                <input class="" type="text" id="products" name="products" readonly style="width: 250px" value="">
                 </div>  
                 
             </div>

 
</div>
```

en el controlador tengo esto

```
 public function index()
    {

         $categorias=Providers::all();
        // $rows= Aircraft::where('user_id', Auth::id())->with('customer')->get();
       /* $rowss = Invoiceorder::latest()->get();
        $filess= InvoiceOrderProduct::latest()->get();
        return view('invoices.invoices', compact('rowss','files'));*/
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $categorias=Providers::all();
          $rowws = InvoiceTemp::latest()->get();
        return view('invoiceorder.create', compact('rowws','categorias'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
```

que segun lo que lei debo pasarle todos los datos de la tabla

este es el ajax que estoy tratando de usar

```
$("#select").onchange(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "/Providers.php?id=".$(this).attr("id"), success: function(result){
        $("#address").val(result.address);
        $("#email").html(result.email);
    }});
});
```

estas son las rutas

```
Route::resource('invoiceorder', 'InvoicesorderController');
Route::get('invoiceorder/create', 'InvoicesorderController@create');
Route::get('invoiceorder/{id}/edit', 'InvoicesorderController@edit');
Route::get('invoiceorder/{id}/edite', 'InvoicesorderController@edite');
Route::put('invoiceorder/{id}', 'InvoicesorderController@update');
```

en mi controlador ya llame mi tabla de proveedores y por eso puedo traer el nombre

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Invoiceorder;
use App\InvoiceorderProduct;
use App\InvoiceTemp;
use App\Providers;
use Auth;
use DB;
```

Comment: vi este ejemplo pero no se como adaptarlo ```$("#select").onchange(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "/Providers.php?id=".$(this).attr("id"), success: function(result){
        $("#address").val(result.address);
        $("#email").html(result.email);
    }});
});

Comment: Deja ver si entiendo, cuando tú elijas uno de los usuarios que aparecen en tu Select, los campos se llenen de manera en automático? Cómo tienes los métodos de tu controlador? Me refiero a `store, create e index`?

Comment: @EdgarGc si eso exactamente lo que quiero lograr

Comment: @BetaM gracias ya creo que puse todo

Comment: @BetaM eso lo vi en un ejemplo y no se como ponerle la ruta par poder generar la peticion

Comment: @BetaM en el create

Comment: @ BetaM si esa exactamente

Answer (score 0):

No es tan complicado. Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

En `routes.php` creas una ruta para obtener los datos del proveedor cada vez que el select cambie.

```
Route::get('provider/{id}', 'ProviderController@getProviderById');
```

Tu método, en el controlador, debería ser así

```
public function getProviderById($id)
{
    $provider = Providers::find($id);
    
    return $provider;
}
```

En tu vista, debemos capturar el evento de cambio del `select` y hacer una petición `ajax` para obtener los datos del proveedor.

```
$("#select").onchange(function(){
      $.ajax({
      url: "provider/"+ id,
      type: 'GET',
      success: function (result) {
           $("#address").val(result.address);
           $("#email").html(result.email);   
      }
    })

});
```